# UIImagePicker Front Camera strange behavior on orientation in iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, camera

**Scenario**

An app that captures an image from `Front camera` automatically after 3 sec countdown.
Everything is working as expected.

**Code**

//in `viewDidLoad`

```
 if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]){
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
self.imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
self.imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
[self.imagePicker.view setFrame:kAppFrame];
[self.view addSubview:self.imagePicker.view];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.imagePicker.view];
}
```

**Problem**
I have never told the ipad to use its rear device Still in certain cases the rear camera starts.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Hold the camera in `Landscape orientation`
2. Click a photo (Will take you to next screen, pushed in Nav controller)
3. In the next screen tilt the ipad halfway towards `face up orientation`
4. Comeback to camera screen and you see it using rear camera.

This is a very strange behavior I am not even able to understand its cause.

Comment: can you say more specific on your step 3 ?

Comment: @CocoaMatters Simply tilting the ipad in the next screen (that was pushed from camera screen) and coming back to camera screen was the issue. there is no technical/better way to tell the step 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I have found the solution.
 just moving the entire code to `viewWillAppear` from `viewDidLoad` method.

It looked like I was relying a lot on view before it appeared with a certain orientation. Putting the code in `viewWillAppear` guaranteed me that the view is actually ready with its orientation set. I can now put anything on it.

I know this is not the proper answer but this is what I made out of the scenario. Any modifications/correction are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

check your code the line `self.imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;`  define that you open your front vamera of device.

Now your second problem: i am not sure but you have to rotate your image 90 degree. It's may be when you get image it's get in portrait mode.

Comment: ,Yes, the image was rotating 90 degree but I wrote a category to adjust its orientation and that is no more a problem.

Comment: I din't understood what exactly you mean to say in the first two lines of your answer. Is there anything that I am missing or doing wrongly.

Comment: I'm using `UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront` in iOS6 and it's still activating the back camera...

Comment: @Clay sorry i haven't any iOS 6 enable device. so i can't help you